# ThreadPoolExecutor is not executing concurrently?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

This is for my academic purpose only. Are the tasks that we add to the executor service are really executing  in parallel. Well this is my example that raised this question

**Runnable Class**

```
public Tasks implement Runnable{
int taskCount;

public Tasks(int count){
this.taskCount = count;
}

public void run(){
System.out.println("In Task :"+taskcount +" run method");
}

}
```

**Main Class**

```
Class MyTest {
public static void main(String args[]){
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

     for(inti=0;i<10;i++){
     Tasks taskObj = new Tasks(i);
     service.submit(taskObj);
   }
   service.shutdown();
}
}
```

As soon as i submit a taskObj to the executor, the taskObj run() is invoked. 
What if i have to something like this,

1. Add all the taskObj to the executor , the run() must not get invoked
2. Execute all the task objects at one shot. All the taskobj run() must be executed in parallel/concurrently

Please let me know

Thanks...V

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, one way to solve this would be to use thread barriers. This might sound strange, but is actually implemented quite easy. You just take a variable (lets name it traffic-light) and make every thread loop on it. If you started enough threads (starting a new thread might consume some time) you just change it to green and all your threads will start execution at the same time.

For academic purposes we used to take an atomic-integer as counter (initialized with 0) and started n threads. The task of each threads was to increase the counter and then loop on it until it reached n. Like this you'll have all threads as parallel as possible.

If you still want to go with a thread pool system, you might have to implement your own thread system, where threads can wait upon a signal prior to grabbing work.

good luck